# special character in using "setfacl" command

Tags: linux

i'm trying to set permission in folder with special character ,

`setfacl -m u:Paul:rwx ?manager`

The directory name is  ?manager  , but due to character ? gives error all time.
how can i overcome this problem?

Comment: Change the folder's name.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122740/how-to-rename-filename-with-or-in-file-name

Answer (score 0):

Quote it

```
setfacl -m u:Paul:rwx \?manager
```

Comment: What distro and version are you using? What shell interpeter?

Comment: centos 6 , bash

Comment: Tried in Centos 6 also. It seems working both quoting and without quoting the question mark. What is exactly the error you got?

Comment: i also have error when in directory with #manager    
setfacl: ?manager: Operation not supported
setfacl: #manager: Operation not supported

Comment: Rename the file to take out special chars (run `mv \?manager manager`), then try again with the new name - I suspect the error might not actually be related to the special char...

Comment: @DanComilescu is right. "Operation not supported" means the partition holding your file system doesn't support acl. Find the partition (e.g /dev/sda2 ) and remount it with acl option (e.g. mount -t ext3 -o remount,acl /dev/sda2 /YourMountPoint ). Change /etc/fstab accordingly to take it after reboot ( /dev/sda2         /YourMountPoint      ext3     acl     0 0 ). To avoid /etc/fstab change, you can set acl as default mount option ( tune2fs -o acl /dev/sda2. )